# Why does urlfetchApp in google appscript is giving timeout error?

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, timeoutexception

I am trying to get response from nseindia.com. From last month it's giving timeout error. Before that it worked perfectly. Do i have to use any additional methods? Did website put some kind of block?

```js
function debugoc2(){
    var url = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10006&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17";
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{muteHttpExceptions: true});
    var rc = response.getResponseCode();
    Logger.log(rc);
    var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
    var content = fileBlob.getDataAsString();
    Logger.log(content);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671314/extracting-a-table-in-google-apps-script-using-urlfetchapp)?

Comment: How long did it take?

Comment: Hello @Srinivas Piccalo! I did try the code you provided but I am getting a `200 response`, so most likely the problem is not the code snippet you have shared. Have you tried it again? Are you calling the function somewhere else - if so, could you please those code snippets as well? Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for trying the code. I observe it's not working during market times i.e 8:00 to 16:00 IST. Then i am getting timeout error after 60 seconds exactly. I think the website blocked me. Please tell me a workaround.